# Postfix Mail Relay - Only permit sending to specific emails

Tags: redirect, block, postfix-mta

I am learning how to configure postfix. I would like to setup a mail relay to only forward emails for specific recipients email addresses and block, or even better redirect to the block addresses to generic account for investigation.

The relay will be used in a development environment and I want to ensure that production emails addresses are not accidentally used in development or testing. As a specific example I would like to create a list of emails address recipients that mail is permitted to be forwarded to eg:
  dev@example.com
  test@example.com

Block any other address that the relay is asked to forward for example.com.  Ideally I would like to forward all blocked to an account check@example.com to investigate.

Could some one point me to the section of the postfix configuration file I should look into?

Thanks

Densha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do a couple parts to the setup.

Part 1 is your allowed list.  What emails are allowed to be sent out.  If this list will change frequently you'll want to look into using an external lookup like mysql for this.  If you use flat files in the postfix configuration directory then you'll have to restart postfix for each change.  With mysql it will perform a new lookup each time, no restart.  Postfixadmin is a tool that may help in this case.

For your 2nd problem of redirecting all mail to another account for investigation see this other solution.

https://serverfault.com/questions/144325/how-to-redirect-all-postfix-emails-to-one-external-email-address